# How can I Retrive Values from DBCurser from mongoDB in a servlet?

Tags: mongodb, servlets

How can I Retrive Values from DBCurser from mongoDB in a servlet:

```
DBCursor cursor1 = user.find();
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
    while (cursor1.hasNext()) {
         jarray.put(cursor1.next());
    }
```

Comment: I want to retrieve the individual values from the documents in the collections with in the database(mongo DB).... For Example: If i've stored encrypted value in the document to decrypt i need to obtain that value from the document...     { "_id" : ObjectId("50634d86be4617f17bb159cd"), "item" : "bottle", "qty" : 30 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50634dbcbe4617f17bb159d0"), "item" : "paper", "qty" : 100 }

Comment: I want to retrieve the individual values from the documents in the collections with in the database(mongo DB).... For Example: If i've stored encrypted value in the document to decrypt i need to obtain that value from the document...   I want only File content so that I can decrypt it...                                                                                               { "_id" : ObjectId("50634d86be4617f17bb159cd"), "File_content" : "klsdjfhsadfh", "qty" : 30 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50634dbcbe4617f17bb159d0"), "File_content" : "klsdsdojdgfio", "qty" : 100 }